# Hibernate cascade + composite id's issue

Tags: java, database, hibernate, firebird, myeclipse

I'm currently learning Hibernate, and I've stumbled into this issue:
I have defined 3 entities: User, Module, Permission. Both user and module have a one-to-many relationship with Permission, so that Permission's composite id consists of idUser and idModule. The user class has a property that is a set of Permission's and it is appropriately annotated with @OneToMany, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, etc.

Now, I generated the classes with MyEclipse's reverse engineering feature. The id of permission was created as a separate class that has an idUser and idModule property. I thought I could create a User, add some new permissions to it, and thus saving the user would cascade the operation, and permissions would be saved automatically. This is true except that the operation causes an exception. I run the following code:

```
Permission p = new Permission();
p.setId(new PermissionId(null, module.getId());
user.getPermissions().add(p);
session.save(user);
```

The problem I have is that, even though the SQL is being generated correctly (first saves User, then Permission), I get an error from the database driver (Firebird) which states that it can't insert a null value for idUser, which is true, but shouldn't hibernate be passing the newly created user id to the second query?

This particular scenario feels very counter-intuitive to me since I'm inclined to pass a null id to the Permission object since it is new and I want it to be created, but on other hand, I have to set the idModule property since the module already exists, so I don't really understand how an operation like this is supposed to work.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a [cascade action](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-cascades) for Hibernate to perform when you save a `User` with an attached transient (meaning not-yet-saved) `Permission`.

By the way, you might want to consider using a different ID strategy for the `Permission` object, such as a generated ID value - how can the primary key of the `permission` row in the database contain a null value?

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't Cascade.ALL work for all actions? The Permission object can't have a null value. The problem is that I have to set its idUser property to null, since the user hasn't been created yet. I thought that the cascade operation would pass this value to the Permission object once the user object was persisted. Like I said, the operation is generating both queries (insert user, insert permission) it's just that the part that inserts the permission doesn't have access to the newly created user id.

Comment: If you intend for the Permission id to be generated, you shouldn't set it to a non-null value. Hibernate needs to know whether it should generate an ID for the entity or not - and the default way of doing that is by using an unsaved-value of null for IDs - see this part of [the manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-update). Note though that it refers to difficulties doing this with composite Ids. Finally, my suggestion about using a generated value (such as autoincrement) was for the Permission ID, not Permission.

Comment: The problem is that in this case, since the id is composite, one part of the id is new (the user id) and the other is not (the modue id is from a module object that already exists). So I have to set at least the module part of the id manually, otherwise it won't link to the module entity properly. But, if I understand correctly, I have to leave the whole id property as null, otherwise it wont work?

Comment: Thanks, that part of the manual doesn't show how it can be done with composite id's though. I'm beginning to think that this is simply not supported in this scenario. I think I'm going to insert Permission objects manually instead.